# Adding a complex dynamic filter in SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

Good day everyone I have a question in regards with queries having a many filters.Below is a sample picture of my data. Let's assume this data came from the `contact` object.
[image]

If I try to query the contact record to check if this 3 email exist, I can do like this.

```
Select Email from Contact where email IN ('john@doe.gmail.com','mike@yahoo.com','test@test.com')
```

My question is how will I do a query to check if the email,firstName,LastName exist without using loop. Fields to be filter is dynamic. Is it possible ? What are the possible way to do this ? If I will do a query like this, I believe that this will not work as I want.

`Select Email from Contact where email IN ('john@doe.gmail.com','mike@yahoo.com','test@test.com') AND firstName IN('john','mike','test') AND lastName in ('doe','wew','sample')`

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered SOSL? It sounds like it may be a better fit for this type of search.

```
Use the Salesforce Object Search Language (SOSL) to construct text
searches. SOSL queries can be used for text searches in the following
environments.

 - the search() call Apex statements Visualforce
 - controllers and getter methods
 - the Schema Explorer of the Eclipse Toolkit

Unlike SOQL, which can only query one object at a time, SOSL
enables you to search text, email, and phone fields for multiple
objects simultaneously.
```

[SOSL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl.htm)

There is a great Trailhead module covering SOSL [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_database/apex_database_sosl) which should give you enough knowledge to use it to meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you ... I did not usually use SOSL. Can you give me a sample SOSL code using the data in my question ?

Comment: Complete the linked Trailhead module, it will give you a good foundation on how to use SOSL.

Comment: How does SOSL avoid the problem of when the aim is to match "John Doe" and "Jane Smith" that "John Smith" and "Jane Doe" also get matched using the and/in construct in the question?

Comment: @DavinCasey Yeah keith C question is one thing in my mind. I think there no big difference from SOQL and SOSL except that SOSL can be used in multiple objects.

Comment: You're right, I missed the AND part of your requirement. The simplest option might be a Contact trigger to populate a checkbox if the Contact matches the criteria, then search for this checkbox value when querying for Contacts. Use a fieldset / custom setting to allow the criteria to be dynamic.

Comment: @DavinCasey Thank you but it wont meet my requirement. What I only want is an SOQL because i need it in my apex class.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a formula field that appends the 3 fields you want to check (with a delimiter value to separate the fields if you want):

```
where Forumla__c in ('john@doe.gmail.com:john:doe', 'mike@yahoo.com:mike:wew', ...)
```

Comment: This would be a good idea. The problem is that I believe this only applicable if you know the exact fields to append. But in my case there the fields to check is dynamic.

Comment: @Hope Fair enough. Suggest you edit your question to make this clear.